# Why different size of different data types in C++

Tags: c++, string, char, size, primitive-types

I have some questions about how to calculate the size of different data types in C++, I have `int`, `char`, `unsigned char`, `unsigned int`, `double`, `string`, after I run the `sizeof(i)`, the computer gave me the answer of `sizeof(int/unsigned int)==4; sizeof(char/unsigned char)==1; sizeof(string)==32;`. I studied in many different tutorials recently, just got very confused about this result, and some claim that `unsigned int` size is 8 bytes, a kind like that, really confusing.....
By the way, I'm really confused about the difference between `char` and `string`, when I declare a `string`, I say `string mystring="asd";`. I also can declare a `char mystring = "asd";`. It is really confusing too, I am just a beginner, hope somebody could help me go to the right direction.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: `I also can declare a char mystring = "asd";` No you can't. About the sizes, why should they be equal? And some sizes depend on your computer, OS, compiler...

Comment: THANKS!! That was a typo, it supposed to be like this:

Comment: char mystring[20] = "hello";

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well for the size of the data types, you dont have to worry much about it. You can always use the `sizeof();` operator to always check the size of the the data types. Theres is no need because the sizes of the different data types depends on the types of computer and operating systems. And for the `string` and `char`, actually string is just an object made a series of `char`. so if you use `string` to declare a string that string becomes an object of the class `string`. And if you use `char` to declare a string (By the way which is actually declared as a pointer type `char*`) then that string is just a series of characters of the type `char`. You can also declare a string using an array. For example `char name[9] = Christina`. So actually there are many ways to declare a string depending on its purpose. But the string object has a lot more functionalities so it. Check out [string object c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string) for more information about the string object. I hope this could help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am just confused about the basic concepts, it really takes time.

Answer (score 2):

C++ was originally based on C, which was made to be a language to  closely follow the hardware. And for hardware it makes sense to have many different data-types of different size (bytes, half-words, words, etc,), so it makes sense for C to follow that and this was inherited by C++ (which can also be used to make programs that run close to the hardware).

The size of the data-types depends on the compilers and the hardware it target, and can differ between platforms and even between different compilers on the same platform. For example, on a 64-bit Windows system, using the Visual Studio the type `long` is 32 bits (four bytes) while using GCC a `long` is 64 bits (eight bytes).

Generally speaking you can say that

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
```

Also, the C++ specification says that `sizeof(char)` is *always* `1` no matter the actual size of a `char`. There is also no difference between an unsigned and a signed type, `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(signed int)`.

As for the size of structures and classes, roughly speaking the size of a structure or class is the sum of size of the members in the structure or class. So if you have a structure (or class) with two `int` member variables, then the size of the structure (or class) will be `sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)`. This is however not the full truth, as the compiler may add padding to a structure to make member variables to end up on nicely aligned positions inside the structure, and this padding is also counted when getting the size of a structure.

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful. I just get it started because c++ sometimes is not that simple, it depends on so much concepts.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard is very open about what the size of various data types is; implementations are allowed to vary a lot.

As a quick summary of the rules:

- sizeof(char) == 1
- sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
- I don't know offhand what the relationship between sizeof(int) and sizeof(unsigned int) is; the standard *might* specify that they must be equal, but I wouldn't rely on it.

sizeof(int) on modern desktops is typically either 4 or 8, depending on that compiler's approach to 64-bit numbers. But you shouldn't assume that.

The reason sizeof(std::string) and sizeof(char) are different is that char is the type of the smallest addressable unit in the system, and C strings are just an array of them. So if you write `char* a = "abcd"; std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;` you will get the size of a pointer-to-char in the system. std::string, on the other hand, is a class. `std::string a = "abcd"; std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;` will give you the full size of the std::string class, including padding, function tables, every member of std::string, etc..

Comment: Thanks, It is very clear now, I think computer is amazing!